# How to deserialize a CoNLL format dependency tree with ClearNLP?

Tags: java, nlp, deserialization, parse-tree, clearnlp

Dependency parsing using ClearNLP creates a `DEPTree` object. I have parsed a large corpus and serialized all the data in CoNLL format (e.g., [this ClearNLP page on Google code](https://code.google.com/p/clearnlp/wiki/NLPComponents#Data_Format)).

But I can't figure out how to deserialize them. ClearNLP provides a `DEPTree#toStringCoNLL()` method (scroll down [this page](http://code.google.com/p/clearnlp/source/browse/src/main/java/com/googlecode/clearnlp/dependency/DEPTree.java?r=cac4fff0433b157d31f504753aaec8f06eb70cf0) to see it). I am looking for something to read a CoNLL format parse tree and create a `DEPTree` object. I tried to reverse-engineer it, but didn't really understand the inner workings of the code.

I have, instead, created my own dependency tree class to handle the basic functionalities I need, but I would really like to know how to get a `DEPTree` object instead. So far, I haven't found any method in their API which does this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, so sharing the wisdom on SO :-) ...

The deserialization can be done using the `TSVReader` in the `edu.emory.clir.clearnlp.reader` package.

```
public void readCoNLL(String inputFile) throws Exception {
    TSVReader reader = new TSVReader(0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7);
    reader.open(new FileInputStream(inputFile));
    DEPTree tree;
    while ((tree = reader.next()) != null)
        System.out.println(tree.toString(DEPNode::toStringDEP));
}
```

This is provided [here](https://github.com/clir/clearnlp-tutorial/blob/master/src/main/java/edu/emory/clir/clearnlp/tutorial/CoNLLFormatTutorial.java) by the author of [ClearNLP](http://nlp.mathcs.emory.edu/index.php/portfolios/clearnlp/), Jinho Choi.

In older versions (< 3.x) you will need to use the `com.clearnlp.reader.DEPReader` class instead of `TSVReader`.